# Why isn't it possible to change the MAC from WiFi adapter from Toshiba U920T

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, mac, powershell

I need to change the MAC address of a WiFi adapter. The steps I have tried include:

1. Open Registry

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
2. Search the key for WiFi Adapter
3. Create a new String Value called `NamedAddress` and set the value to the new  MAC address starting with `60-6C-...`
4. Disable the network adapter
5. Enable the network adapter
6. Use PowerShell as an administrator
7. `Set-NetAdapter -Name WiFi -MacAddress "60-6C..."`
8. Confirm the question for execution with "Y"

I am receiving this error message:

[image: error message]

Is it possible that the network adapter doesn't support this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130875.aspx) of `Set-NetAdapter` says:

> -MacAddress (String)
>
> Specifies the current MAC address of the network adapter. Dashes are
>   optional as part of the input. **Not all network adapters support**
>   **setting the MAC address**. The address passed in is also saved in the
>   network addresses property without dashes.

So based on the error message you provided, I guess your Network Adapter doesnt support this function